# How to use tikzducks on Plain TeX / ConTeXt?

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, plain-tex, tikzducks

Is it possible to use/port `tikzducks` in Plain TeX or ConTeXt? As far as I know, `tikzducks.sty` has some LaTeX-isms as `\begin .. \end` environments, so it doesn't work outside LaTeX.

Comment: It crashes in ConTeXt.

Comment: plain and context users should think themselves lucky that they are spared the duck plague.

Comment: Create a separate document with `standalone` and include it as an image (and don't listen to @DavidCarlisle, he eats pineapple pizza)

Comment: @CarLaTeX and ducks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For ConTeXt users, my attempt to get TikZ ducks:

1. I deleted LaTeX headers from `tikzducks.sty` and added the following ones:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usecolors[xwi]
\usemodule[tikz]
\enabledirectives[colors.pgf]
\usetikzlibrary[patterns] % for the wizard hat
\usetikzlibrary[calc] % for the sports jerseys
```

2. Delete @ from command names as it was sort of troublesome.
3. Replace some commands by its ConTeXt counterparts, e.g. `\starttikzpicture .. \stoptikzpicture` for `\begin{tikzpicture} .. \end{tikzpicture}`.
4. Redefined `\duck` according to ConTeXt syntax:

```
\def\duck{\dosingleempty\doduck}
\def\doduck[#1]{%
\iffirstargument
\startscope%
\tikzset{/duck/.cd,#1}%
\duckdraw%
\stopscope%
\else
\startscope%
\tikzset{/duck/.cd}%
\duckdraw%
\stopscope%
\fi 
}
```

5. Some other minor changes.

Although the color palette is a bit messed up because of the ConTeXt color management (e.g. ConTeXt `gray` looks like LaTeX `lightgray`), the final result is quite acceptable.

The following code:

```
%\environment_tikzducks and your .tex file must be in the same folder
%unless you use subpath structure, e.g. subfolder/environment_tikzducks
\environment environment_tikzducks
\starttext 
Ducks in \CONTEXT\ go brrr
\startcolumns[n=3]
\dorecurse{20}{%
\starttikzpicture \randuck \stoptikzpicture%

}
\stopcolumns 
\stoptext
```

gives the output:
[image]

For anyone interested, I'm sharing the edited code [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Iul6V0CukfNNzN_vvvNdoMWrnH8dtK0Q)

### EDIT

Sam Carter, the maintainer of tikzducks accepted my pull request to add a ConTeXt wrapper, so finally tikzducks is available in TeXLive. Just do:

```
\usemodule[tikzducks]
\usecolors[xwi]
```

and now you can use `\tikzducks` and related inside ConTeXt's `\starttikzpicture ... \stoptikzpicture`. It should work fine in LuaMetaTeX, too. Feel free to do suggestions [here](https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks/pull/25). A Metapost counterpart would be nice btw.

Comment: If you would replace format-specific things like `\start…` by the generic form, I'm sure this would be a great pull request to the package.

Comment: Where should I ask? I'd be happy to see ConTeXt users, including myself, using TikZ ducks and friends

Comment: What do you mean by asking? If you need help transitioning to the generic forms of commands or testing for the format TeX.SX is the right place. If you are ready, a pull request can be opened at https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks.

Comment: @TeXnician My pull request has been accepted. I'm gonna edit my answer soon. Soon it will be only a matter of making `\usemodule[tikzducks]\usecolors[xwi]`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your effort :)